# How to convert .tiff images into .jpeg format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rmagick, attachment-fu

I am using Attachment_fu to upload images.

I need to convert .tiff images into .jpeg format after uploading image in application.

I used below code:

```
 :styles => {
    :thumb => ["150x172#",:jpg],
    :large => ["100%", :jpg]
  },
```

But it is not useful for me.

Please help me how to convert image format?

Answer (score 0):

As already implied in your tags [ImageMagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/) will do the trick.
You can either use the `convert` command line utility or use its ruby binding [RMagic](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/usage.html).
In the latter case you just have to read the image and write it again with the new name.
The above documentation says:

```
require 'RMagick'
include Magick

cat = ImageList.new("Cheetah.jpg")
smallcat = cat.minify
smallcat.display
smallcat.write("Small-Cheetah.gif")
```

You can also read and write from a string if you do not want the file on disk.

Comment: Please precise the question if you had something else in mind.